# Undefined callback in function

Tags: node.js

I have this function

```
function isPlayerBanned(name,isbanned){
fs.readFile('bans.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    var retorna;

    var banFile = JSON.parse(data);
    var isBanned = false;
    if ( banFile[name] !== undefined ) {
        isBanned = true;
    }
    if (isBanned){
        var banExpiration = banFile[name];
        var actualTime = new Date();
        var banDate = new Date(banExpiration);
        var timeban = banDate.getTime();
        var time = actualTime.getTime();
        if (time > timeban){
            console.log("oi");
            retorna =  false;
        } else {
            console.log("falhou denovo :(");
            retorna =  true;
        }
    } else {
        console.log('fail 2');
        retorna =  false;
    }
    return isbanned(retorna);
});
```

}

And when I use :

```
isPlayerBanned(WHOIS.account, function(banned){
            if (banned){
                bot.say(channel,from + ": You can't add because you are banned. Use !isbanned [yourauthname] to know when the ban will expire.");
            } else {
```

Node throws that error: "undefined is not a function"
Why is it saying that 'isbanned' is undefined,if it's on the function?

Comment: take a look at `return isbanned()` line, you are calling it, what exactly is `isbanned` parameter supposed to be?

Comment: I tested your code with some minor modifications (to make it run) and it works - check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jeden/9370122). I tested with the `isBanned` variable set to false and true, and in both cases no error has been reported

Comment: @GeoPhoenix : it's supposed to be a function,that is called later with the isPlayerBanned(ie: the second code I posted in the question)

Comment: @Antonio : When I ran your code,it didin't throw any errors too,but when I run mine,it throws that error

Comment: Sorry.It was my mistake. I had that old line of code :  
console.log(isPlayerBanned(WHOIS.account));  
Which was throwing the error.Sorry for that.It's 'fixed' now.

Comment: @Lucas: glad to know it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
function parse(str){
    try { 
        var parsed = JSON.parse(str);
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
    return parsed;
}

// pay attention to the use of "return" to evade indentation! 

// returns 2 arguments in callback 
// 1. error (== null, if no error)
// 2. true (user is banned) or false (user is not banned)
function isPlayerBanned(name, cb){
    fs.readFile('bans.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) return cb(err);

        var bans = parse(data);
        if (!bans) return cb("JSON.parse failed");

        // if username not in ban list, he is not banned!
        if (!bans[name]) return cb(null, false);            

        // username in ban list, check if ban still active

        var bannedTil = bans[name]; // UNIX timestamp in millisecs
        var now = Date.now(); // UNIX timestamp in millisecs

        // if ban is set to last till a lter point in time
        // than the current time! User is still banned!
        if (bannedTil > now) return cb(null, true);  

        // ban has expired, user not banned anymore
        cb(null, false);

        // TODO: delete the user from the bans.json file
        // if his ban has expired
        // tip: use an event, it's not relevant to the user           
    });
}

isPlayerBanned(WHOIS.account, function(err, banned){
    if (err) return cb(err);

    // banned is true or false, see isPlayerBanned
    if (banned){
        bot.say(channel,from + ": You can't add because you are banned. 
                Use !isbanned [yourauthname] to know when the ban will expire.");
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```